# how to save xml in user's computer in coldfusion?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I am invoking a ColdFusion webservice through cfinvoke

```
<cfinvoke
   method="getUsers"
   returnvariable="rawXMLUserList"
   webservice="http://www.xyz.com/getusers.cfc?wsdl"
>
  <cfinvokeargument name="userid" value="123">
</cfinvoke>
```

And I am storing XML returnvariable into `userList` variable

```
<cfset userList = XmlParse(rawXMLUserLis)><br/>
```

how to save abc.xml on user's computer, using cffile it is saving on server's computer, i have to save it on user's computer who invokes this "getUsers" method.
Thanks
Kishor

Comment: The user would need to be given the file as a browser download where they can then choose to save it locally:- http://www.coldfusioncookbook.com/entry/39/How-do-I-force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-displaying-inline-in-IE,-Firefox-and-other-browsers

Comment: You can't force a user to save it. At most you can force the user to choose to download it as @James Buckingham answers below.

Comment: You don't specify what you need to do with the xml file once it is on the user's computer.  Do you (the website maintainer) need continued direct access to that file, or do you want the end user to have direct access?  If the former, the chosen answer won't work easily, since the user will be responsible for re-uploading it whenever you need access.  As an alternative, you could store the XML in the browser's localStorage container, which would keep it on their machine but keep it available to you directly.  If that is what you want, let me know and I can provide a more complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run XMLParse(), you're turning it into a CF XML Document Object.  You need to use ColdFusion's toString(xmlObject) function when outputting it.

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=abc.xml">
<cfcontent type="application/xml;charset=utf-8" reset="true">
<cfoutput>#toString(userList)#</cfoutput>
```

Another way is to write the file to a web directory (cffile action=write) and then cflocation the user to the file.

Comment: .. and if you are not using `#userList#` elsewhere, you could skip `XMLParse` altogether and just return the original xml string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the user's browser to download the file, not display it. Generally with something like this (not tested):

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=abc.xml">
<cfcontent type="application/xml;charset=utf-8" reset="true">
<cfoutput>#userList#</cfoutput>
```

`cfheader` generates a custom HTTP header.

`cfcontent` sets the MIME content encoding header for the page.